# Determine "nil" value in JSON

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The app receives JSON object from the server. And some field in the object can be missing, or be `nil`. So, I need to find them before computing a value. I have a code fragment as below:

```
print(package["store"]!["cover"]) //here, console output: "nil"
if ((package["store"]!["cover"]) != nil) {
    //the 'if' statment above has no effect, statment below is executed,
    // and error occurs.
    imageName = STATIC_IMAGE_URL + (package["cover"] as! String)
}
```

How can I detect if the response JSON has some missing or nil fields?

Comment: It is not very clear what you need. Do you want to detect if the response json has some missing or nil fields?

Comment: Why don't you just use if-let statement for cover instead of ["store"]!["cover"] i.e. if let cover = package["cover"] { imageName = STATIC_IMAGE_URL + (package["cover"] as! String) }

Comment: to  Cristik: I do need to detect if the response json has some missing or nil fields.

Comment: to  Anni S: I know the if-let method could work, I just wonder why the 'if' statement can not work.

Comment: to Anni S: And in my situation, the if-let method also has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333), and [conditional casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID341) combined in the same `if-let` statement:

```
if let cover = package["store"]?["cover"] as? String {
    imageName = STATIC_IMAGE_URL + cover
} else {
    imageName = "someDefaultImage"
}
```

It works like this:

- `package["store"]?["cover"]` will return `nil` if either `package["store"]`, or `package["store"]["cover"]` is nil
- the conditional cast `as? String` returns nil if the expression to the left is not a `String`
- finally the `if-let` construct will either populate `cover` with the actual string, or will go on the `else` branch if there's no match

Comment: It's OK. Thanks a lot!