# json missing fields swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

So I have a function that pulls data from a json file and parses it. Its throwing me a nil error because some of the json entries don't have the "colors" field/array. How would i account for this and put in "ERROR" as the text for the ones that didn't.

```
  func getData2(){

    let dataPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cardata", ofType: "json")
    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfFile: dataPath!)
    {
        do
        {
            if let dictionariesArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as?
                [[String: AnyObject]]
            {
                for dictionary in dictionariesArray
                {
                    let name = dictionary["name"] as! String
                    let type = dictionary["type"] as! String
                    let text = String(dictionary["text"])
                    if let printingsArray = dictionary["colors"] as? [String]
                    {
                        let printingsString = String(printingsArray.joinWithSeparator("-"))
                        nameColor[name] = printingsString
                    }
                    nameType[name] = type
                    nameText[name] = text
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            print("Could not parse file at")
        }
    }

    struct Card {
        let name: String
        let type: String
        let colorr: String
        let textt: String

        init(name: String, type: String, textt: String, colorr:String) {
            self.name = name
            self.type = type
            self.textt = textt
            self.colorr = colorr

        }
    }

    var goodCard = [Card]()

    for (cardName, cardType) in nameType {
         let cardText = nameText[cardName]!
         let cardColor = nameColor[cardName]! //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

        goodCard.append(Card(name: cardName, type: cardType, textt: cardText, colorr: cardColor))
    }

    if typee != "" {  
      let redDogs = goodCard.filter {$0.type == typee}
        print(redDogs)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine "nil" value in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509114/determine-nil-value-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the forced unwrapping operator `!` whenever possible. If you use it and the `Optional` is `nil` then when you use the variable it will throw an exception. Instead use [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) to unwrap the value:

```
// optional binding
if let cardColor = nameColor[cardName] {
  // do something with the value
}
```